# Check above form field is correctly fill out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `HTML` form with some form fields.

My Markup is something similar to this -

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My question is, I want to keep second form field inactively (in this form it is `email field) till first form field is correctly fill out. Inactive mean user cannot type or paste any thing there.

Can anybody tell is this possible in jquery, if so tell me how?

Hope someone will guide me to correct path. 
Thank you.

Comment: yes it is possible with jquery.

Comment: This is possible you just need to know about `blur` apply blur when the 1st form field is filled

Comment: Define "correctly filled out"

Answer (score 0):

Add disabled attribute to email and enable/disable on name keyup

HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('input.name').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $('input.email').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('input.email').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/m2h5fc9b/

Comment: You are better off using `prop()` instead of `attr()` http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing If first name contain numbers or any other symbol remain I want to keep `disabled` attribute on email filed.

Comment: @TNK replace `if( $(this).val() )` with `if( $(this).val().trim().match(/^\w+$/) )`

Comment: I tried it something like you have mentioned from last comment. But I couldn't figure out. This is how I tried it - http://jsfiddle.net/m2h5fc9b/3/